# how to get struct field type in golang?

Tags: go

```
type Role int

type User struct {
    Id int64
    Name string
    Role Role
}

func ListFields(a interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    for j := 0; j < v.NumField(); j++ {
        f := v.Field(j)
        n := v.Type().Field(j).Name
        t := f.Type().String()
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s  Kind: %s  Type: %s\n", n, f.Kind(), t)
    }
}

func main() {

    var u User
    ListFields(&u)
}
```

go run main.go

Name: Id  Kind: int64  Type: int64

Name: Name  Kind: string  Type: string

Name: Role  Kind: int  Type: main.Role  <--- how to get int type ?

Comment: The reflect API does not provide a way to get the underlying type of some type.  In this example, there's not a way to get `reflect.TypeOf(int(0))` from a `reflect.TypeOf(Role(0))`.  You can use [Type.Kind](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.Kind) to reflect on the underlying type.  Why do you need to get the `int` type?

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks,I neglected Kind() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go `Kind()` returns the basic types (this is what you're asking for) and `Type()` returns the direct types (what you've defined as custom types). You'll never get the basic type from `Type()` for any custom types you've defined. I've modified your example a bit to help you understand that `Kind()` always returns the actual basic type (or kind of type, see https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind), despite many nested custom types.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Role int
type Role2 Role
type Role3 Role2

type User struct {
    Id   int64
    Name string
    Role Role3
}

func ListFields(a interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    for j := 0; j < v.NumField(); j++ {
        f := v.Field(j)
        n := v.Type().Field(j).Name
        t := f.Type().String()
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s  Basic Type or Kind: %s  Direct or Custom Type: %s\n", n, f.Kind(), t)
    }
}

func main() {

    var u User
    ListFields(&u)
}
```

https://goplay.space/#-eTlN4dGzj_k

In other words both Kind and Type are types. They match for basic types (int64, string, etc.) and differ for custom types. There is no reason to substitute the Type value with Kind.